# When can a design pattern make your software worse?

Tags: design-patterns, separation-of-concerns, anti-patterns

When can a design pattern make your software worse?

I have seen a program where they used the facade pattern between the GUI and logic. They considered that no objects may be transported over this, so only primitive types were used which made it difficult to code.

Comment: Obviously, when you misuse a pattern it only makes your design worse.

Comment: a design pattern applied in the wrong place? or applied badly?

Comment: Actually that application of the facade pattern could be a good idea in some circumstances - such as where interoperability between heterogeneous systems is important.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For decades programmers have often spent time making software *worse* by **applying practices they don't understand, rather than learning why that practice is good.**  The use of certain tools/keywords/frameworkes can make a programmer feel sophisticated, when they're just screwing things up.  Some common examples:

- Throwing in lots of try/catch/finally blocks can make a programmer feel like they have an error handling scheme, when in fact they don't.
- Replacing sql with stored procedures can make programmers feel like they have a data access layer that magically gives them efficiency, reuseability, encapsulation, when in fact they don't.
- Using classes makes many programmers believe they're engaging in object oriented programming, when in fact they aren't (or are only scratching the surface of OO).

This list could go on forever.  This tendency has always been around and always will be, because we humans always look for shortcuts.  We see this a lot with **patterns** now because patterns are currently popular.  The root problem is the same:  developers not having a respect for how complicated software development is, and thinking a blindly implemented pattern or practice is a substitute for learning and humility.

The solution?  Difficult to say.  You can't go to wrong though handing a junior developer [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) or some such, to help them understand this is all about applying principles to *particular situations*, and that great developers keep it simple.

Answer (score 21):

When you misuse it, or, sometimes worse, when you use a pattern unneccessarily.  The latter drives me nuts because when I analyze a piece of code, I naturally first assume there's a reason for everything in there, and when I can't see a reason for something, the safest default assumption is that I'm missing something.  And since I don't want to risk breaking code in unknown or unpredictable ways, I waste time trying to figure out why it's in there before I mess with it.

Comment: Yes. Every line of code costs time to read, understand and maintain it. If it is not worth this time, it is just a waste of money.

Comment: @Charles: "And since I don't want to risk breaking code in unknown or unpredictable ways" this is what a design pattern is for. If you cannot interpret a correctly used design pattern (which imo the question implies) you need to learn the design pattern, which usually is easier than the business code since there are so many references for it, contrary to for example badly documented inhouse productions.

Comment: @chelmertz, I may be completely missing yr point (I'm afraid you were not clear to me) but my comment is specifically about those cases where a design pattern is used where it is not needed and is unneccessary.

Comment: @Charles: I think we understand eachother, but also have different opinions :) Since I think design patterns are the closest things to textbook examples of solutions to common problem areas, they're clever as they are (generalizing a bit). A wrongfully applied "solution" can't be blamed on the pattern itself, it's as if you'd complain about a programming syntax which **does what it says it does, not what you want it to do**.

Comment: @chelmerz,  At the risk of repeating myself, I am still confused.  Taken literally, I agree with both your comments completely, but I don't see how they connect to my post.  I am not criticising design patterns at all. Far from it, I am an advocate. I use them (in code, in documentation, and in conversation) all the time, and in the mentoring that I do I recommend learning about them to my co-workers.  No, my post is critiquing the use of a pattern (or technique, whether you call it a pattern or not) where it is not required, and only obfuscates the design, just because patterns are "cool"

Comment: (con't) .... which is an example of how "  the use of design patterns can make your code worse "   ... which is what the OP was asking.

Comment: Compare with a function multiply_by_two(int val). Functions are good. But since there's no obvious reason to put multiply by two functionality into its own function, it should be done when, and only when, there's a good reason for it (eg. you may have to change the value of two, the underlying architecture may need some special instruction, etc). So it's a big red flag if you see that function and can't find the reason.

Comment: I think what Charles is trying to say is, as a simplified example, if a piece of code used a factory method and singleton pattern for producing random numbers when all it needs is Random.GetNext(). Even if it's a very well implemented example of a factory method and singleton pattern, the thing which wastes time isn't understanding how it works. The question is "why the hell are they going to all this trouble instead of just going Random.GetNext()".

Answer (score 4):

When it's name is **[singleton](http://www.twonine.co.uk/articles/SingletonTheAnti-Pattern.pdf)**

Comment: And it isn't an logger of some sort.

Comment: When you apply general rules like "always use pattern Xyz" or "never use pattern Xyz", for instance "never use Singleton". (Although I've seen mostly bad example for Singletons, I think the best way to misuse patterns and make your code worse, is by blindly applying any kind of rule.)

Comment: Singletons wrapping a Properties object that won't change during runtime are actually a pretty good use of the pattern.

Comment: In my book, Singletons are only OK when they don't have any state. When they represent behavior only, then I like them.

Comment: Singletons that don't have any state are a hack around the fact that not EVERY problem can (or should) be solved in an object-oriented way, and sometimes you just need logically grouped free functions.

Answer (score 3):

A design pattern can make your software worse if you misuse it, **applying it in a wrong situation**. Common sense should be the perfect companion for a design pattern.

The misuse of patterns sometimes is associated with a **lack of understanding of the forces** associated with the problem and the pattern proposed solution to that problem. Also the intent of the pattern could be misunderstood leading to misuses.

To a better comprehension of patterns you also need to **learn about the [Anti pattern](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki/wiki?AntiPattern) concept** and read a lot more than the GOF book. One suggestion is to read [Pattern Hatching](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201432935) to complement GOF's concepts.

Answer (score 3):

A Design Pattern is simply a way of Naming and Documenting a common code structure. As such, you should not conclude that all patterns are good ones. The people that do a good job of documenting design patterns (eg the GoF) always include a section in the pattern description describing when you should, and should not, use the pattern. As such half the point of most design pattern books is to answer the question "When can a design pattern make your software worse?"

Many inexperienced developers never bother to learn the appropriate uses section and end up applying patterns where they are inappropriate. I think this is the cause of a lot of the negativity surrounding design patterns.

In conclusion the answer to this question should really be:- Go and read the design pattern and it will tell you.

Answer (score 2):

It's interesting that, over the past year, I've invested a fair amount of time learning Design Patterns and their implementations - just as there seems to be a growing blow-back against Design Patterns. Design Patterns have, fairly or not, joined the ranks of processes and methodologies that were supposed to make software a quantifiable skill - i.e., the fallacy that using them would make you write better code. I think the problem with Design Patterns is that less skilled programmers use them as a "Golden Hammer". They learn the Strategy Pattern - which is a valuable thing - but then they use it *everywhere*, over-complicating their code and adding unnecessary features and "expandability".

I believe there is immense value in *refactoring* to patterns, because you're cleaning up existing code. Patterns are also valuable communication tools, that let you describe your code in higher-level terms. But stuffing Design Patterns into your software because they're Cool and Marketable (a.k.a "Resume-Driven Development") is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

What makes easy difficult (EJB)

Answer (score 1):

When it's the wrong pattern for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when a coder takes the attitude that patterns are the lego-like bricks one builds software out of, you get some really odd code.

Answer (score 1):

The software will get worse when you use design patterns as absolute building-blocks, instead of as blue-prints to help solve coding problems.

They weren't meant to be the blocks in which the problem is framed. They shouldn't show up in the Object naming conventions. Objects shouldn't be called *Factory or *Singleton, or any other pattern name. They shouldn't be locked to a specific pattern.

They are just really good "starting points" to help one build complex code more rapidly. You can (and should) mix and match the ideas as needed. Documentation? That's what the comments are for, not the Object namespace ...

Paul.

Answer (score 1):

It is called anti-pattern, and please refer to AntiPatterns: Refactoring Software, Architectures, and Projects in Crisis book for examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about antipatterns [here](http://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns), for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) can make software worse if it's not needed.  The strategy pattern basically makes a piece of functionality "pluggable", meaning we can switch out different implementations on the fly.  But this pluggable functionality often adds a lot of complexity (and sometimes extra overhead) with configuration, and if it's not needed, it's a waste. I see this pattern abused quite often.

Comment: Any pattern can make the software worse if it's not needed...

Comment: Yes, however a see the strategy pattern abused a lot because making functionality "pluggable" seems "cool", but often times it isn't needed and just overcomplicates things.

Answer (score 0):

Levi,
  I would only use a specific pattern if it made my life (and those that are responsible for maintaining the code) easier.  I believe that proper design pattern selection  is just as important as comments - maybe comments are more important?  You'll find that design patterns, for the most part, formally describe techniques that we as developers have used for years.

TheEruditeTroglodyte

Answer (score 0):

Any pattern that is mis-understood or mis-applied would tend to make the code worse not better. Also, any pattern that is applied just for the sake of the pattern, e.g. "We're SOA now!".
Generally if a pattern introduces a "[code-smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)" then its use should be suspect.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say whenever you choose a pattern based on solving one problem, and not all of the problems your software intends to solve.

Conversely, trying to over-engineer a solution to fit all possible eventual use cases can lead you to using a design pattern that is too bulky to fit the majority of your use cases.

So the ideal pattern/level of adherence to that pattern would be something that falls between the two extremes.

Answer (score 0):

I can think a lot of ways a design patter can go wrong. The GoF book explains the problem, solution and drawbacks for all patterns it talks about.
- A pattern is a solution to a problem. If that problem is not your problem, then it's probably it's going to become an antipattern.
- A pattern has drawbacks, and you should be aware of them.
- When you don't need it. A pattern may imply a lot of classes, and you're trying to solve a problem you may have in the future but don't have yet.
- If you don't understand how it works and you implement it wrong, it becomes an antipattern as well. You're gonna end up with a lot of useless classes and code.
- When you start to get addicted to it. Hierarchies that are too deep, bad use of polimorphism or singletons, etc. can pose a problem.

There are probably other reasons as well...

Answer (score 0):

When people analyze the code and spend more time trying to understand the pattern than the business logic. Patterns are good, but only if everyone involved knows how to read them.